# Make id ex disappear if you click anywhere outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how I can make a targeted element disappear. If you click any where that is outside of that element. I have created a toggle effect with a button but I want to also hide id ex if there is any clicks outside of ex. I have

found working sources on this subject but it's based on jQuery most of the time. I have nothing against jQuery I just need to do this in pure JS structure for 
personal reasons.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#ex{
display: none;
}
</style>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
    var b= document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
    b.addEventListener('click',fx);
function fx() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ex");
    if (x.style.display === "block") {
        x.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
}
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Toggle</button>
<h1 id="ex">Blablablablabla bla bla JS</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
Any time I tried to ask this question on this topic on many sites nobody never understand what I mean. In other words I don't want the body to do any toggling just the button the best way I can explain this is like this you know how in some applications if you click on a drop down menu and you click out side of that drop down menu then it disappears but you can use the navigation bar button to bring it back? That's what i'm trying to do .

I want something like this but in pure JS structure.

```html
<style>
  #ex{
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#ex').click(function(execute){
    execute.stopPropagation();
});
$('button').click(function(execute) {
    execute.preventDefault();
    execute.stopPropagation();
    $('#ex').toggle();
});
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#ex').hide();
});
    });
</script>
<button>Toggle</button>
<h1 id='ex'>Blablablablabla bla bla JS</h1>
```

Comment: so basically you want to hide the element if they click anywhere which isn't either the element itself or the button?

Comment: Yes sorry I'm a bad explainer some times :( but I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <style>
    #ex{
    display: none;
    }
    </style>
    
    <script>
  document.addEventListener("click", function(obj){
     var x = document.getElementById("ex");
    if(obj.target.id != "ex") {
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
        } else  if(obj.target.id == "btn") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
  });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="btn">Toggle</button>
    <h1 id="ex">Blablablablabla bla bla JS</h1>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: mohammad javad ahmadi I'm trying to have the button the only thing that toggles it. In other words if you click anywhere that is not the id ex element or the button the id ex element  disappears. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @fsofb try it now

Comment: thanks for your reply mohammad javad ahmadi I did that's not what i'm looking for I don't want to toggle the body I want the button to do that toggle thing only not the body. I don't think your understanding what I mean  the best way I can describe this is like this you know how in some applications if you click on a drop down menu and you click out side of that drop down menu then it disappears but you can use the navigation bar button to bring it back? That's what i'm trying to do .

Comment: Thank you mohammad javad ahmadi so much sorry i'm not good at explaining things but thank you this is what I was talking about.

Comment: mohammad javad ahmadi this does not work with fire fox it gives this error TypeError: obj.srcElement is undefined but I fixed it so I was wondering if you would update your code with this instead  so future readers can have this working on firefox    document.addEventListener("click", function(obj){
     var x = document.getElementById("ex");
    if(obj.target.id != "ex") {
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
        } else  if(obj.target.id == "btn") {
            x.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
  });

Comment: mohammad javad ahmadi never mind I updated your code sorry i'm new I did not know I can update others code but thank you tho.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You can save the button id and compare it with the clicked element id.

```
var b= document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
var btnId = b.getAttribute('id');
document.addEventListener('click',fx);
  function fx(e) {
      var x = document.getElementById("ex");
      if (e.target.getAttribute('id') == btnId) {
          if(x.style.display == "block")
              x.style.display = "none";
          else 
              x.style.display = "block";                    
       }
       else{  // we did not click on button
           if (e.target.getAttribute('id') != 'ex')
               x.style.display = 'none';
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys and Farzin Kanzi look at my updated post question I added what I mean in better details. Look at the jQuery example. That's what I want but in pure JS structure just toggle the button and click anywhere that is not element id ex or the button and you will know what I mean.

Comment: @fsofb Did you use my code on the head of your page?? It was obvious that it must be used in an srcipt tag **after** the button and the toggling element